# Import directive in ionic2 - ng2-qrcode

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2, angular-directive

I trying use the **ng2-qrcode** in my test **ionic2** app, but this never found the directive, follow the `ionic serve` output:

> serve  /?restart=454981  (www/index.html) serve  /cordova.js  (mocked)
>   serve  /build/js/es6-shim.min.js serve  /build/js/Reflect.js serve 
>   /build/js/zone.js serve  /build/js/app.bundle.js serve 
>   /build/css/app.md.css serve  /build/app.html serve 
>   /build/pages/page1/page1.html 0     045123   log      Angular 2 is
>   running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the
>   production mode. 1     045125   warn     Native: tried calling
>   StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to
>   include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator 2     045159   group
>   EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No Directive annotation found
>   on QRCodeComponent 3     045160   error    EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught
>   (in promise): No Directive annotation found on QRCodeComponent 4
>   045160   error    STACKTRACE: 5     045161   error
>   resolvePromise@http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:538:32
>   resolvePromise@http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:523:18
>   scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:571:18
>   Zonehttp://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:356:24
>   NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:35178:32
>   Zonehttp://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:355:24
>   Zonehttp://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:256:29
>   drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:474:26
>   ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:426:22
>
> 6     045161   groupEnd  7     045162   error    Unhandled Promise
>   rejection:, No Directive annotation found on QRCodeComponent, ; Zone:,
>   angular, ; Task:, Promise.then, ; Value:, [object Object]

I follow the [readme](https://github.com/PragmaticClub/ng2-qrcode) on GitHub and do:

> npm install ng2-qrcode

Create a Class with component annotation:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {QRCodeComponent} from 'ng2-qrcode'

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html',
  directives: [QRCodeComponent],
})
export class Page1
{
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController ) { }
}
```

And put the tag in template **build/pages/page1/page1.html**:

```
<qrcode qrdata="'My QR code data string'" size="256" level="'M'"></qrcode>
```

But I'm getting this error, what is wrong? Is hard do find Ionic2 explanations or documentations and I'm very beginner in Ionic2 and typescript.

Comment: have you found the solution? I have the same problem

Comment: yes, see the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow the solution from [@yahyaKacem](https://github.com/yahyaKacem) in issue "**[mport QRCode with typescript import](https://github.com/PragmaticClub/ng2-qrcode/issues/1)**", here's a [`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/zEzqUfrnjehG84wm16De?p=preview) with an example.

I dont test the last version, but maybe a newer version will work ( exist a merge related to this issue ).

Answer (score 0):

For those who liked the original ng2-qrcode as well, I refactored ng2-qrcode to make it work with Ionic3 (and Angular4+). angularx-qrcode is basically a drop-in-replacement for ng2-qrcode written in TypeScript with the same APIs plus AOT compilation and webpack bundling.

The Repo **angularx-qrcode** is here:
https://github.com/Cordobo/angularx-qrcode

Let me know, if this works for you.